# How to raise append elements in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements inside a **class** and I want to attach it to another **Id**, and I used the following code :

`$(function() {$("#sid-li")["append"]($(".lt-fo"));});`

The code works fine, but the **class** elements come under the **id** elements .
I want class elements to be above id elements
is there a solution ?

Comment: Please provide sample of relevant html as per [mcve] and expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the container element of your elements with that class.

```
$("#sid-li").append($(".lt-fo:first").parent())
```

That's what you are looking for, right?

Comment: No, I want class elements to be above id elements

Comment: Then, if you want to copy those class elements, you need to append them to the prev() element of $("#sid-li") or prepend() them to the parent of that element.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem can be used **prepend()**